# Show posts of a specific category first in WordPress loop

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to show posts from a category first in the homepage and then continue the default order of WordPress posts.

Is it even possible?

I've tried using 2 loops and filter the first one with the category that I want however I don't think that the pagination will work as expected.

Comment: You're trying to do this with filters or using a custom template?

Comment: Custom template...

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested code, though).

```
$total_posts_to_display = 10; // Change accordingly

$id_of_category_1 = 4; // Change accordingly

$filtered_posts = array(); // Array to be filled in with all posts, ordered by "category 1" first

$posts_in_category_1 = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => $total_posts_to_display,
    'category'    => $id_of_category_1
) );

$ramaining_posts_number = $total_posts_to_display - count( $posts_in_category_1 );

if ( $ramaining_posts_number > 1 ) {
   $excluded_post_ids = array();
   foreach( $posts_in_category_1 as $ep ) {
       array_push( $excluded_post_ids, $ep->ID );
   }
   $remaining_posts = get_posts( array(
       'numberposts' => $ramaining_posts_number,
       'exclude'     => $excluded_post_ids
   ) );
} else {
   $remaining_posts = array();
}

$filtered_posts = array_merge( $posts_in_category_1, $remaining_posts );
```

I have a more sophisticated solution that will support pagination too! You will need to place it in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_home_post_ordering' );

function my_custom_home_post_ordering( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_home() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }
    $posts_in_category_1 = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'category'       => 4 // Change accordingly. You may also use 'category_name', instead.
        'fields'         => 'ids'
    ) );
    $query->set( 'post__in', $posts_in_category_1 );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'post__in' );
}
```

Comment: By the way, i didn't think about pagination here, but at least you have an starting point!

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't work. What you did was the same as `$query->set( 'category__in', 4 );` and this display only the posts for that category. I want to show them first and then show the others.